# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress & r establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
> Hosting: Godaddy
> PHP version: 7.1

I have tried to change the PHP Version from cpanel when I select 7.1 PHP version it gives an error

> Error: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

When I select the native version i.e 5.4 then it gives "Error establishing a database connection".

I have set proper database connection then also it gives "Error establishing a database connection" error.

I am not getting exactly why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Is the php7.1-mysql package installed?
If not, install it!

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql
```

Comment: How can we check and install mysql package. sorry, i am new to this.

Comment: I have used putty to connect to server and tried to install but some cmd we cannot use warning is coming